# Trying to render new Title tag with JQuery and Google Tag Manager

Tags: jquery, google-tag-manager

I am trying to use Google tag manager (GTM) to change the title tag of a page. I am using this tutorial - https://www.searchviu.com/en/javascript-seo-experiments-google-tag-manager/ and the method is effectively:

- Delete existing title tag
- Write new title tag
- Add it to the `<head>`

Here is my script that I am firing via GTM:

```
<script>
  jQuery('title').remove();
  var newtitle = document.createElement('title');
  newtitle.txt = 'HERE IS THE CUSTOM TITLE';
  jQuery('head').append(newtitle);
</script>
```

This seems to be having the effect of deleting the existing title tag and inserting `<title></title>` into the `<head>`

[image: empty title tag]

but the custom text is not being inserted between the title tags (when inspecting in Chrome). Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Cheers!

Comment: Why all this effort? If you just set document.title in a custom HTM tag it will have the same effect with a lot less effort, and without the jQuery dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You simply used the wrong attribute for the select: it is text not txt.

```
jQuery('title').remove();
  var newtitle = document.createElement('title');
  newtitle.text = 'HERE IS THE CUSTOM TITLE';
  jQuery('head').append(newtitle);
```

That said, Eike Pierstorff is entirely right. While I realize organizations often have a firewall between marketers and developers, this approach just feels wrong. Mutating the title is weird and your changes will not be represented in SEO.